# Saving and loading using SharedPreferences doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I've tried using sharedpreferences for saving my ToDoList but unfortunately I am having a difficulties for getting it to work.

This is my code:

```java
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

              loadData();

              ...
    }

    private void loadData() {

        if (initialStart) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = sharedPreferences.getString("task lisk", null);
            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Record>>() {
            }.getType();

            AddItemActivity.listItems = gson.fromJson(json, type);
            initialStart = false;
        }
        if (AddItemActivity.listItems == null) {
            AddItemActivity.listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, AddItemActivity.listItems);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void saveData() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("todo list", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(AddItemActivity.listItems);
        editor.putString("task list", json);
        editor.apply();
    }

 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
```

I created a separate AddItem layout where I created an ArrayList so that's why I'm calling it with AddItemActivity.listItems.

Comment: Did you check that the JSON string is created correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using same **`KEY`** in your `SharedPreferences`

you need to use same key while saving and retrieving data from `SharedPreferences`

> When you getting data from `SharedPreferences` you have used **`"task lisk"`** key 
>   and when you have have saved data in `SharedPreferences`, you have used **`task list`**

LIKE THIS

```
private void loadData() {

        if (initialStart) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("todo list", MODE_PRIVATE);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = sharedPreferences.getString("task_list", null);
            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Record>>() {
            }.getType();

            AddItemActivity.listItems = gson.fromJson(json, type);
            initialStart = false;
        }
        if (AddItemActivity.listItems == null) {
            AddItemActivity.listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, AddItemActivity.listItems);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void saveData() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("todo list", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(AddItemActivity.listItems);
        editor.putString("task_list", json);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `SharedPreference` name must be same for storing and retrieving the  data.

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("todo list", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

You are storing with this name but while you retrieving it is different. So change

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("todo list", MODE_PRIVATE);
```